# How to Uniquely Identify a Mobile Device Without Breaking PII (Personally Identifiable Information) Laws

Tags: personal-information

I work for a small software division of a large non-digital company, and we need a way to identify a mobile device without directly using PII (Personally Identifiable Information).

We know that MAC Address and IMEI number can't be used on their own, but can we use the first half of one and the last half of the other to uniquely identify the device without breaking the PII (Personally Identifiable Information) laws?

Comment: "I work for a small software division of a large non-digital company..." Ask your company legal department.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be primarily a question about technological mechanisms for achieving an end rather than the law itself.

Comment: Even without the legal advice aspect, this is too broad.  There are hundreds of jurisdictions in the world, each with their own set of laws, and each one may have many different laws addressing different aspects of PII.

Comment: Who said that MAC/IMEI can't be used?

Comment: @ohwilleke Just the problem that some "technological mechanisms" can both break the law, and not help you achieve your goal.

Comment: I agree, this question can be closed. We will be asking our organization's legal department.

Thanks everyone for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anywhere where it is in and of itself illegal to uniquely identify a mobile device in software. It's just that, once you have such a unique identifier, it is more or less by definition personally identifiable, you need to handle it in accordance with applicable law.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really much of a law question, but much more a technical one.

Make sure that you understand what you actually want to achieve. For example, say 10 years ago some software company identified my iPad. They identified the actual device. I used a game that they wrote, and my high score was bound to the actual device. So if I had bought a new iPad, and sold the old one, because they actually identified the device itself, my high scores wouldn't have been on my new iPad, but whoever bought the old iPad would have inherited my high score. So if you identify the device itself, that is very very likely a bad idea and will not give you what you want.

If you have software on Apple's app store, you can identify that I am user X. You don't know who I am, but you can take payments (without knowing who I am), deliver items of value (without knowing who I am) and so on. You don't know who I am and cannot figure it out, but you know 100% that I am user X. Another company could use the same method and knows that I am user Y of their app. You can't even join forces and find out that user X of your app is the same as user Y of their app.

So identifying my device is useless. Identifying ME is hard and pointless and most likely illegal. But it might be helpful if you actually describe your purpose behind all that. Not your suggested technical solution, but your actual goal.